# How can I cancel setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote this simple Javascript for auto and manually hiding bootstrap alerts.

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("[data-hide]").on("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
    });
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(700).slideUp(700, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

I want to cancel the `setTimeout` when the cancel button is clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a numeric `timeoutId` for your timer. You can pass that to the `clearTimeout` method.

```
$(function () {    

    var t = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(700).slideUp(700, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 5000);

    $("#yourHideButtonId").on("click", function () {           
      if(t!=null)
      {
          clearTimeout(t);
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To start timer:

```
timer = window.setTimeout(  f , 5000);
```

To clear it:

```
 window.clearTimeout(timer);
```